# Why is Loki introducing himself as Loki of Asgard?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, thor-marvel, loki

In the Avengers, Loki is introducing himself as: Loki of Asgard. Doesn't he have a real surname? Like the surname of one of his fathers? :)

Answer (score 29):

Nordic naming tends to consist of a first name and the name of the parent. Thor, would be Thor Odinson, the son of Odin.

Loki, however, is not Odin's son. He's adopted by him, but his father is the frost giant Laufey. As an adopted Asgardian, he can't very well call himself Loki Laufeyson, so Loki of Asgard it is. He is of Asgard, but the son of no Asgardian.

Comment: Thank you! That´s understandable! :) So before the revelation of his adoption, he called himself Loki Odinson, just like Thor.. :)

Comment: Loki Laufeyson wouldn´t fit, that´s right! lol

Comment: It should be noted that naming isn't consistent across cultures, and surnames are a relatively recent European invention.

Comment: Ah, good to know.. So it´s just Loki.. :)

Comment: Actually, in the Norse, I think Loki was known as ' the Giantsborn' and 'the Wolffather'

Comment: @Jersey Yeah, but that's probably not what he would use to introduce himself. Especially if he wants to play it innocent.

Comment: @Avner: Maybe he should try Robin Goodfellow? It always worked for Puck in the fairy kingdoms, and that was as good a Loki in English Mythology as any.

Comment: Laufey (or Nál) is Loki’s mother, not his father, at least in actual Nordic mythology. He wouldn't be called Loki Laufeyson, because that’s ungrammatical; but he has been quite commonly named ***Loki Laufeyjarson*** (the genitive of _Laufey_ being _Laufeyjar_) in Eddic poetry, so the concept is not new. I suspect it's simply a bit too much of a mouthful for Hollywood movies.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet in Marvel, Laufey is male.

Answer (score 3):

#### He is called 'Loki of Asgard' because the writers of the Marvel movies wanted to keep a bit of suspense as to where Loki came from. Remember the reveal with the [Casket of Ancient Winters](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Casket_of_Ancient_Winters)?

- The naming convention of using one's first name and the name of one's home has been done since the fifth century so it is not an out of place custom, even among the Asgardians.
- In the comics, however, he is indeed called **[Loki Laufeyson](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Loki_Laufeyson_(Earth-616))**. It is well-known he was adopted by the All-Father Odin. If anyone is displeased by this, they tend to keep their opinions to themselves lest they suffer Odin's wrath.

> - **[Loki Laufeyson](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Loki_Laufeyson_(Earth-616))** is the son of **[Queen Farbauti](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Farbauti_(Earth-616))** and **[King Laufey](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Laufey_(Earth-616))**, leader of the Giants of Jotunheim. King Laufey was the leader of the Giants of Jotunheim. He married Farbauti who bore him a son. However, he was born small and was kept in secret away from the other Giants for being an embarrassment to his parents. [Journey into Mystery #112]